# Are java methods allocated different memory sizes based on their return type

Tags: java

Trying to write a memory efficient java script...so it got me wondering...what's in a return type?If I define a method say `String push(String arg)` or `int push(String arg)` with same implementation...will the memory usage be different?

Comment: Not in any significant way, and that's a very poor starting point for memory optimization.

Comment: Are you asking about **java** or **javascript**? If you are asking about `javascript` you should change the tags because java and javascript are not the same and should not be confused.

Comment: I wonder how you can so easily replace `String` with `int`.

Comment: @lexicore Wouldnt there be more overhead from parsing a string as int than simply returning an int in the first place though?

Comment: @MasterYoda You somehow assume it's `int` in the first place. It may or may not be, how would we know.

Comment: How can two methods, one returning a String and the other an int, have the *same implementation*?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException same code body

Comment: Show an example of a code body that is the same for a method returning String and one returning  int

Comment: It is impossible in **Java** (not **Javascript**) to have the 100% exact same body for two such methods. Java does not auto-convert ints to Strings or vice versa. Those two versions must differ at least in that they have explicit conversions in the end, like `return Integer.parseInt(text);` or `return Integer.toString(value);`. If that is not the case for you, you are talking about **Javascript**. In which case your accepted answer is completely invalid, since it talks about **Java**.

Comment: What you are attempting here is premature micro-optimization. This is really really bad for a lot of reasons. Chances are high that you make your code slower with educated guesses. And you make it less readable and maintainable. And more likely to introduce bugs. You should go for the version that makes most sense. Only try to optimize if you identified a performance/memory issue. And then first create a proper way of measuring it, otherwise you can not tell if you made it worse or not (this happens very often).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String` will take more memory (reference value, `char[] value` field, `int hash` field, object header, memory alignment) but replacing it with `int` is a micro opitmization. For a single object the gain is insignificant especially if the returned value is short lived and garbage collected in NewSpace. There are also other things to consider e.g. was your `String` previously interned or stack allocated.

You can inspect the Java Object Layout using [jol](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/):

> JOL (Java Object Layout) is the tiny toolbox to analyze object layout schemes in JVMs. These tools are using Unsafe, JVMTI, and Serviceability Agent (SA) heavily to decoder the actual object layout, footprint, and references. This makes JOL much more accurate than other tools relying on heap dumps, specification assumptions, etc.

Comment: From the comments it almost sounds as if OP is talking about Javascript, not Java (he says the two methods have 100% identical body, which is impossible in Java). If that is the case, this answer is invalid unfortunately.